# using a css3 animation to load a website

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I came across this website the other day and was wondering how to create the same page load effect. Is it jQuery? or CSS3 animations using sprites?

http://www.adhamdannaway.com/

After inspecting the site I found that his loading logo is made up of a sprite image (black logo next to a grey logo). The effect he creates is like the logo is being "filled up" as the page loads (linear effect going up) I have a feeling he is overlaying the black logo with the grey one and then fading the grey logo out in a linear direction either using jQuery and CSS3, or both.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to use aJax to call the content, and while the content is getting loaded, you can show the animation.

When the content is loaded you can make [aJax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) do a the animation to get it in the screen.

The animations to get the page into the site, might be done with jQuery as well.

I did something similar with [aJax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) myself. Try it out.